# MailChimp Integration with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailchimp

I have been messing up with Mailchimp lately and can't figure out a simple thing. I hope anyone of you can help me out. I have following code in my model, an add function and a mailchimp function

```
public function add($arr){
    $arr['token']=$this->random_string(8);
    $subscriber=array(
        'first_name'=>$arr['first_name'],
        'surname'=>$arr['surname'],
        'email'=>$arr['email'],
        'update_at'=>$arr['update_at'],
        'gender'=>$arr['gender'],
        'age_group'=>$arr['age_group'],
        'buying_source'=>$arr['buying_source'],
        'typical_spent_amount'=>$arr['typical_spent_amount'],
        'token'=>$arr['token']
    );
    $this->db->insert('subscribes',$subscriber);
    $this->mailchimp($arr['email'],$arr['token']);
    return $arr['token'];
}


public function mailchimp($emailAddress,$token){
        $this->load->library('mcapi');   
        $listID = '3e4df2c57f'; // obtained by calling lists();
        $retval = $this->mcapi->listSubscribe($listID, $emailAddress);  

        if ($this->mcapi->errorCode): 
            $error="Unable to subscribe email using listSubscribe()!";  
            echo "\n\tCode=".$this->mcapi->errorCode;  
            echo "\n\tMsg=".$this->mcapi->errorMessage."\n";  
        else:
            return TRUE;
        endif;
}
```

The mail Chimp sends a default welcome message and a verification message to the user, what I wanted is to send the generated token to the client too. The mailchimp api mcapi calls a function listSubscribe which takes two parameters listId and email address I am not sure how to send token to that function and then echo it in message

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying mailchimp services, make sure you have initialized the mailchimp library.

```
<?php
$this->load->library('Mailchimp_library');
$lists = $this->Mailchimp_library->call('lists/list');
var_dump($lists):
```

Now subscribe someone to the list

```
<?php
$this->load->library('Mailchimp_library');
$result = $this->Mailchimp_library->call('lists/subscribe', array(
            'id'                => 'b1234346',
            'email'             => array('email'=>'davy@example.com'),
            'merge_vars'        => array('FNAME'=>'Davy', 'LNAME'=>'Jones'),
            'double_optin'      => false,
            'update_existing'   => true,
            'replace_interests' => false,
            'send_welcome'      => false,
        ));
print_r($result);
```

for more details, please review the link
https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/

Good luck !!!

Comment: This is not working for me it give response nothing,

Comment: hy, can you please tell me, as subscribe send me subscription mail before subscribing can you please tell me on how to get email direct to list without sending email